# defining a file handle attribute in moose

Tags: perl, moose, filehandle

I am trying to define a file handle attribute in my Perl code using moose as follows:

```
has validation_log_file_handler => (
   is => 'ro', isa => 'File',  builder => '_build_validation_log_file_handler'
);
```

The builder:

```
sub _build_validation_log_file_handler {
   my ($self) = @_;
   open(my $fh, ">", $self->validation_log_file)
      or die ("ERROR:Can't open file "
         . $self->validation_log_file
         . " for writing");
   return $fh;
}
```

But when trying to write to a file:

```
sub run {
    my ($self) = @_;
    print $self->validation_log_file_handler "Hello\n";
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I new at Moose. Am I doing something wrong? I get the following compilation error:

```
syntax error. String found where operator expected
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Printing to complex filehandles requires curlies:

```
print { $self->validation_log_file_handler } "Hello\n";
```

or you could use the OO notation

```
use IO::Handle;  # Required in older versions of Perl

$self->validation_log_file_handler->print("Hello\n");
```

Did you define a `File` class? If not, use `IO::Handle` as the `isa`.

Comment: Handles aren't `FileHandle` objects; they are IO::Handle or IO::File objects. Not sure how well it works to actually use that as `isa`, though.